# Question about the uses of matrices in games and 3D graphics

Tags: math, 3d, games, matrices

So I know that matrices are used extensively in the field of games and 3D graphics, for example, you need to know how to do matrix multiplication if you want to understand how scaling an object works, or you would need to know how to do matrix addition if you want to translate an object. In short, all pretty simple stuff. My question is about whether more complex matrix operations are ever used in the field of games of 3D graphics. Things such as Gaussian elimination performed on the matrix, or other forms of decomposition. What is the most high-level matrix-related maths I can be expected to perform in the field of games and 3D graphics?

Comment: Hi, I see you are new to the site. While we do encourage conceptual software development questions, you may find a better answer over at (http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/). Also, you may want to check out (http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) at some point or another.

Comment: Yes, if you write shaders you can do all sorts of cool effects with matrixes.

Comment: The "field of games" is only restricted by the inventiveness of game designers. So this is definitely too broad for giving you a sensible answer. The "field of 3D graphics" is a little bit more restricted, but still fills whole books.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is "yes, but not as often".

I doubt that there is an upper limit to how "high-level" matrix math you could possibly need to understand for games and graphics programming, but pragmatically, math applications of any sort tend to get rarer as they get "higher-level".